# Is adding device to subvolume the same as adding device to main filesystem in btrfs?

Tags: filesystem, btrfs

When I add a device to a btrfs sub-volume with

```
btrfs device add /dev/sdb /path/to/subvolume
```

is the added device then only used for the sub-volume or is it used by the whole file-system ?

Or the question in the other way: Is it possible to add a device only to a sub-volume?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a device to a subvolume. You can add a device only to a filesystem.

But this command will work with any path to an object located on a btrfs filesystem.

And it looks like you do not quite understand what subvolume is. Adding a device to a subvolume makes no sense for me at all.

Comment: okay, thanks! so, balancing with ´btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt´ works also with any path of the btrfs filesystem,right?

Comment: Exactly. The object of the path should be on the correct FS. It does not matter which object. But I suggest using the mount point, just not to make a mistake.